# Memory management in for multiple cores of a processor

Tags: computer-engineering, computer-hardware

I come across a question-**'How big an address space should I allocate for each ARM A53 core in a mobile processor?'** What is the answer for this?
Does it refer to memory management in SoC?

Comment: Perhaps better on a computing focused stack.

Comment: This depends on too many factors not shared in the question to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answers to this kind of question would mostly come from knowing the memory behavior of the software you're going to run on it. My advice would be to start with monitoring, then use eg. twice what seems to be a normal level. Without monitoring, you will never get past guessing. Which is quite okay for the initial values, btw.

Comment: What does ''software you're going to run on it'' really refer to? Doesn't it mean or refer to 'operating system'? Also please answer my second question in the first post i.e. "Does it refer to memory management in SoC?"

Comment: It’s often best in StackExchange to just place a single question per entry. What I think such a sentence means is that you can at the hardware / memory management level give quotas to the particular cores. Such a quota would indeed cover the OS, your code, everything. Please give us more information about your aims, context etc. if you wish to get better answers.